# CSS Beautifier Alternative

Tags: html, css

Having a long `css` file I have decided to make it organized and do some reformatting. As there are some tools to do that, I decided to test it with real code, but unfortunately I am experiencing unusable results.

My code contains several sections such as the following example:

```
@-webkit-keyframes flash {
  0%, 50%, 100% {opacity: 1;}  
  25%, 75% {opacity: 0;}
}
```

And these sections are my problem, as `CSS Beautifier` completely destroy them.

What alternatives can be used to reformat css files? I mean properly.

Comment: @cimmanon, I'm not seeing the "off topic-ness" of this question.  Is it because it's likely to solicit opinions?  It seems like if the question was "what is the best CSS Beautifier" I would understand but this is a clear example of some unexpected behavior that Ωmega is looking for an alternative to.

Comment: `What alternatives can be used to reformat css files?` It doesn't seem an `off topic` question because `OP` tried to do something and failed and didn't ask for a tool, instead asked alternative solution to overcome the problem. Not because he didn't mention/ask for any tool but he has a real problem here and it doesn't mean all we answered here should give name of tools, it could be any alternative solutions too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try TidyUp option in http://jsfiddle.net
It produces this result:

```
@-webkit-keyframes flash {
    0%, 50%, 100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    25%, 75% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You may try (online tools) [Procssor](http://procssor.com/process) - Result after process :

```
menu { color: red }
navigation { background-color: #333 /* darkgrey */ }
@-webkit-keyframes flash { 
    0%,
    50%,
    100% { opacity: 1 }
    25%,
    75% { opacity: 0 }
}
```

or [CSS Beautify](http://cssbeautify.com/) Result after process :

```
menu {
    color: red;
}

navigation {
    background-color: #333 /* darkgrey */;
}

@-webkit-keyframes flash {
    0%, 50%, 100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }

    25%, 75% {
        opacity: 0;
    };
}
```

Where original code was

```
menu{color:red} navigation{background-color:#333 /* darkgrey */}
@-webkit-keyframes flash {
0%, 50%, 100% {opacity: 1;}  
25%, 75% {opacity: 0;}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- Use TidyUp opetion in JSFiddle
- and if using Dreamweaver

  - Go to Commands Menu

    - Apply Source Formating

This will format you complete CSS file